# How to edit the table value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
.
.
export default function test(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
       {id: 1, name: 'paper', qty: 10},
       {id: 2, name: 'bottle', qty: 10},
    ]);

    const handleEdit = () => {
           ....
    }
return (
<div>
   {data.map((row) => (
      <TableRow>
         <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
         <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
         <TableCell>{row.qty}</TableCell>
         <TableCell>
            <Button onClick={()=> handleEdit()}> <EditIcon/> </Button>
          </TableCell>                                            
      </TableRow>
     ))}
 </div>
  )
}
```

I'd like to make the `qty` field editable of that specific row on the table by clicking on `EditIcon`. What should `handleEdit()` would be like?

Comment: Could you provide us with info from where did `TableCell` component come from?

Comment: Content could be made editable by attaching a handler to it. Guide for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac It is the React library called material-UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a isEditable flag to store the state.

```
const [isEditable, setEditable] = useState(false)
```

Then, inside handleEdit(), toggle the value,

```
const handleEdit = () =>{
  setEditable(!isEditable)
}
```

and inside render, conditionally render cell value or input field.

```
{ isEditable ? 
  <TableCell><input type=text /></TableCell> :
  <TableCell>{row.qty}</TableCell> 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace the qty field with inputbox on button click .
on imput change update the qyt field
on pressing Enter inside the input box again replace the input box with div

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can call a function handleEdit() on click of qty. Take Input field for it. and enable it only when user clicks on qty. Otherwise it's disabled and can be read only.